# How to make @angular/cdk/drag-drop cdkDropListConnectedTo works cross iframe?

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I have two lists of drag-drop references to each other.
List A using `cdkDropListConnectedTo` to connect to list B.
If list B is a normal component, it's working fine.
But, for some reason, I have to load list B into an iframe ([Components inside an iframe (and data binding) in Angular](https://medium.com/swlh/components-inside-iframe-and-data-binding-in-angular-ac10eb6ab54b)) and List A cannot drag and drop items to list B anymore.
I tried to research and read the source code of `angular/cdk` but still have no idea what to do.
I hope you can help, I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not make the cdkDrag enter the iframe. Once the cursor reached the iframe boundaries, it stuck.

My workaround was to **hide** the iframe (don't remove from the DOM) and display a cdkDropList component instead when List A emits a dragStart. The new component UI can be something like "Drop your stuffs here." box and belongs to the same `document` as List A. If anything is dropped in there, you can notify the iframe programmatically and propagate the dropped data (`postMessage`, `new Event`, etc.).